# ruby: delegate if object responds to method

Tags: ruby, delegates, activesupport

I'd like to use delegation in Ruby, but I can't guarantee that the target object responds to all method I will call. May I define delegation with a default behaviour?

E.g.

```
class DummyPresenter
  delegate :name, :age, :to => :@content, :default => nil
  def initialize(content)
    @content = content
  end
end

class Student
  def name
    "name"
  end
end    

> DummyPresenter.new(Student.new).age # => nil
> DummyPresenter.new(Student.new).name # => "name"
```

Now, the above example would raise:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `age' for #<Student:0xa121212>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it using `define_method`:

```
class DummyPresenter

  @@delegated_methods = [:name, :age]
  @@delegated_methods.each do |method|
    define_method(method) do
      return @content.try(method) if @content.respond_to?(method)
      nil
    end
  end

 def initialize(content)
   @content = content
 end
```

end

Comment: Is there any point in using try if you've already checked that the method exists?

Answer (score 4):

```
def method_missing(method, *args)
  if @content.respond_to? method
    @content.send method, *args
  else
    #your default behaviour (or super)
  end 
end
```

also u can use DelegateClass it will do the same trick.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'd like the `DummyPresenter` to `respond_to` add delegated methods, so [I used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11189730/580346) `define_method`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the easiest way to delegate methods to the original object is with SimpleDelegator (ships in stdlib)

```
class Presenter < SimpleDelegator

  def initialize model
    super model
  end

  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end

class Person
  def bam
    'baz'
  end
end

person = Person.new
presenter = Presenter.new Person

presenter.foo # => 'bar'
presenter.bam # => 'baz'
```

From the docs:

> SimpleDelegator class provides the means to delegate all supported
>   method calls to the object passed into the constructor

Answer (score 0):

How about not using delegate and doing it manually like this?

```
class DummyPresenter
  def initialize content; @content = content end
  def name; @content.respond_to?( :name ) ? @content.name : dflt_name end
  def age; @content.respond_to?( :age ) ? @content.age :dflt_age end
  def to; @content.respond_to?( :to ) ? @content.to :dflt_to end
  def dflt_name
    nil # or whathever code
  end
  def dflt_age; nil end
  def dflt_to; nil end
end
```

Or otherwise you'd have to reprogram delegate method, I think...

Comment: Hm, that's the thing I'd like to avoid, because there is lot of copied code that differs only in the method name.

Comment: @mrzasa That's easy to fix though with a little refactoring.